# Image not displaying on server side react

Tags: reactjs, image, express, webpack

I ran into a 'syntax error: Invalid or unexpected token' when I try to display image through  SSR. The code runs successfully when I use image tag with return method but will refuse to run when the image tag with the src is constructed as below.

```
  App.js

import React from "react";
import Olatunji from "olatunji"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="contacts">
      <div className="contact-card">
        <img src={Olatunji} alt="olatunji" />
        <h1>Name NumberOne</h1>
        <p>Phone No: 09033344422</p>
        <p>Email: nameOne@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the code of `Olatunji` ?

Comment: "Olatunji" is only referencing the image. Olatunji is representing "olatunji.jpg" image file.